# Are these proofs of two theorems regarding the Hilbert system correct?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Note: This post considers **propositional logic**, with $\to$, $\neg$ as the base connectives. 
Consider  a usual Hilbert-style proof system(with modus-ponens as the sole inference rule) with the following axioms,

- $\phi \to \left( \psi \to \phi \right)$
- $(\phi \to (\psi \to \gamma))\to ((\phi\to \psi)\to(\phi \to \gamma))$
- $(\neg \phi \to \neg \psi) \to ((\neg \phi \to \psi) \to \phi)$

Say a set, $\Sigma$, is inconsistent iff there exists a $\psi$ such that $\Sigma\vdash\psi$ and $\Sigma\vdash\neg \psi$. A set is consistent iff it’s not consistent.
I want to prove:

- 1. If $\Sigma$ is a consistent set and $\Sigma\vdash p$ then $\Sigma \cup \{p\}$ is consistent
- 2. If $\Sigma\not\vdash p$ then $\Sigma\cup\{\neg p\}$ is consistent

Here are my proofs:
1. Suppose that $\Sigma$ is consistent, $\Sigma\vdash p$ and  for the sake of contradiction there is a formula $\psi$, such that $\psi$ such that $\Sigma\cup\{p\}\vdash\psi$ and $\Sigma\cup\{p\}\vdash\neg \psi$, then by the first axiom and Modus Ponens $\Sigma\cup\{p\}\vdash\neg\neg p \to \neg \psi$ and $\Sigma\cup\{p\}\vdash\neg\neg p \to \psi$, by the third axiom and Modus Ponens twice we have $\Sigma\cup\{p\}\vdash \neg p$, applying the deduction theorem we have that $\Sigma\vdash p\to\neg p$, using $\Sigma\vdash p$ and Modus Ponens  we have $\Sigma\vdash\neg p$, a contradiction to $\Sigma$ being consistent.

2. Suppose $\Sigma\not\vdash p$ and for the sake of contradiction that there is a formula $\psi$ such that $\Sigma\cup\{\neg p\}\vdash\psi$ and $\Sigma\cup\{\neg p\}\vdash\neg \psi$, then by the deduction theorem we have $\Sigma\vdash\neg p\to\neg\psi$ and $\Sigma\vdash\neg p\to\psi$, using the third axiom and Modus Ponens twice we have $\Sigma\vdash p$ a contradiction.
Are my proofs correct? Or are there any inaccuracies/mistakes?How can we prove every consitent set is conatined in a complete consistent set using these lemmas? (Assuming the wffs are countable)

Comment: For 1, why not just have $\Sigma\cup\{p\}\vdash \psi,$ $\Sigma\cup \{p\}\vdash\lnot\psi,$ then by deduction thm, $\Sigma\vdash p\to \psi$ and $\Sigma\vdash p\to \lnot \psi,$ and then by MP and $\Sigma\vdash p,$ conclude $\Sigma\vdash\psi$ and $\Sigma\vdash \lnot\psi$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, why not write an answer?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Are these Lemma”s enough to prove that every consistent set is contained in a complete consistent set?

Comment: It shows for any sentence $p$, a consistent theory can be extended to a consistent theory that decides $p$. To show this means there is a complete consistent extension, you need to iterate this over every sentence, or use Zorn’s lemma (or ultrafilter lemma).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen And to show to that I suppose we’ll need a another lemma that exactly one of $S\cup\{\phi\}$ , $S\cup\{\neg\phi\}$ is consistent, assuming $S$ is .

Comment: No, they can both be consistent

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Could you please add an answer saying how to prove that every set is contained in a complete consistent set(see my edit) assuimng all wffs are countable, I'd definitely upvote and accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are correct. The first one can be significantly simplified, though. If $\Sigma\cup \{p\}$ is inconsistent, the deduction theorem gives $\Sigma\vdash p\to \psi$ and $\Sigma \vdash p\to \lnot\psi,$ and then since $\Sigma\vdash p,$ you can apply modus ponens to show $\Sigma$ is inconsistent.

As for your second question, since the sentences are countable, enumerate them $p_0,p_1,\ldots$. Let $\Sigma$ be some consistent set of sentences. Let $\Sigma_0=\Sigma,$ and then recursively define $\Sigma_{n+1}$ to be $\Sigma_n\cup\{p_n\}$ if it is consistent, otherwise $\Sigma_n\cup\{\lnot p_n\}.$ By the results you proved, $\Sigma_{n+1}$ is consistent if $\Sigma_n$ is. Now, just check that $\bigcup_n \Sigma_n$ is a complete, consistent extension of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Proving a maximally consistent set, is deductively closed requires an additional (proof by contradiction lemma) right? Using complete sets avoids that.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re getting at, but that a maximal consistent set is deductively closed follows quickly from what you proved.

Comment: How?Could you please elaborate?

Comment: #1 pretty much says this exactly… if you prove something and it’s not in the set, the set isn’t maximal.

Comment: So no where in the proof of completeness we used that $T\cup\{\phi\}$ is inconsistent implies that $T$ proves $\phi$ if go either the maximally consistent way or complete way. Correct?